# Access Button Tap In Unit test SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xctest, xctestcase

I'm trying to access the button click in the Unit test class. I'm not able to perform action.

**Button AppCode:-**

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Button(action: {
            print("Button Cicked")
        }) {
            Text("Testing")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .accessibility(label: Text("Testing"))
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

**Unit Class Code:-**

```
class testBtnClickked: XCTestCase {

func testtestBtnClickked() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let deleteButton = app.buttons["Testing"]
    deleteButton.click()    
  }
}
```

> Error:- No target application path specified via test configuration: <XCTestConfiguration: 0x7fb315a11a80>

**[image: ScreenShot]**

Can someone please explain to me how to access the button click in the XCTest Class, I've tried to with above code but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64953369/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi, sorry i already tried this. but i'm getting error. Please check attached screenshot

Comment: @Asperi, i already configured Properly and it's working properly in another unit class with same project. I'm really confused why it's not working in the particular class.

Comment: @Asperi i'm using your code also and getting same error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64953369/17395036

Comment: Just copy-pasted and test with Xcode 13.1 / iOS 15.1: no changes since post - compiled and tested ok.

Comment: Yes, i'm doing same. I have tested in Xcode 13.1/ iOS 15.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs, because i'm not using the UI test class. I'm using UI test code in the Unit Class.
After Create the Different UI test Class, the same code working perfectly.